# PHP xml_parse_into_struct breaks because of &acute

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to converting xml into PHP array. the problem is xml_parse_into_struct only converts the string before it encounters the `&acute`. I have the following code.

```
$xmlStr     = file_get_contents($url);
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING   , "UTF-8");
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING      , 0);
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE        , 1);
xml_parse_into_struct($parser, trim($contents)          , $xml_values);
```

when viewed as HTML it is like `there´s`.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You're using the old XML extension released with PHP/4. It's a horrible dinosaur that makes you take care yourself of every tiny implementation detail. I honestly suggest you drop it and use [anything else](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&acute;` is an unknown named entity in XML, you can no load it as plain XML, only as (X)HTML.

You can use DOMDocument to load HTML, but by default this will "repair" the document to a complete html file:

```
$html = '<p>there&acute;s an acute</p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>there&#xB4;s an acute</p></body></html>
```

You can see that the `&acute;` got converted to its numeric encoding. This is valid in XML, the named entity is not (Not without a DTD, XSD).

Here is another approach, you can decode all the named entities to utf-8 using string functions:

```
$html = '<p>there&acute;s an acute</p>';

$namedEntities = array_flip(
  array_diff(
    get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
    get_html_translation_table(HTML_SPECIALCHARS, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8')
  )
);
$xml = strtr($html, $namedEntities);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<p>there&#xB4;s an acute</p>
```

This will work even with the old extension you're using at the moment:

```
$html = '<p>there&acute;s an acute</p>';

$namedEntities = array_flip(
  array_diff(
    get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
    get_html_translation_table(HTML_SPECIALCHARS, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8')
  )
);

$xml = strtr($html, $namedEntities);

$parser = xml_parser_create ('utf-8');
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $xml, $xml_values);

var_dump($xml_values);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["tag"]=>
    string(1) "p"
    ["type"]=>
    string(8) "complete"
    ["level"]=>
    int(1)
    ["value"]=>
    string(17) "there´s an acute"
  }
}
```

Comment: Now this is out of the world answer. Thanks

Comment: I have another question, see if you can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216522/get-xml-code-count-using-xmlreader

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

e.g.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml_string = file_get_contents($url);
$xml_string = html_entity_decode($xml_string, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
$xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_string);
var_dump($xml_data); // displays object array
```

Comment: still no luck. the problem with simple XML is it returns following error. `parser error : Entity 'acute' not defined`

Comment: Can you add this line `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` above the code that loads the SimpleXMLElement? I wan't to see what the internal error is.

Comment: not getting `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'`

Comment: Can you post your xml? I'd like to try parsing it on my machine locally.

Comment: its simple xml file that comes with default open cart. just download open cart, enable google base and you will have the xml file.